# Cordova_not_available error when testing on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to follow this guide - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bogYgE7aYL8

Having followed the first section (up to around 4mins), I test the scan button from on my device and I get an error saying -

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both ionic and cordova, but no luck. Also, I run -

```
Cordova -v
```

And get a return saying version 8.0.0 is installed.

Comment: check whether the barcode plugin has been installed by using the command cordova plugin ls

Comment: Just checked now using that command. It shows it as being installed.

Comment: Were you testing on web, emulator or phone? If emulator, did you check whether the plugin is supported on an emulator?